# NURBS Path not extending all the way to tips

Tags: python, bezier-curves, vertices

I have two Path objects that I've joined into a single object here for comparison.

[image]

The one above was generated with [a Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120111/2952). The one below was added the typical way from the menu Add > Curve > Path

The trouble is, in the one above the curve doesn't reach the tip vertices, making it hard to control where the resulting curve will begin and end.

For example, this sphere has a Follow Path constraint on it, but that path begins at an arbitrary point. It's not useful.

[image]

What property of the vertices determines this, and how can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Noted in other link closed as dupe. Use the `spline.use_endpoints_u` (and v) to extend a NURBS to its extremities.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127603/how-to-specify-nurbs-path-vertices-in-python   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194400/adding-a-hook-to-a-nurbs-path-with-python  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you!! I was really spinning my wheels with this one. Didn't know about this property of NURBS verts until today, and couldn't even find it in the UI. In [the answer I'm using as my main reference](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120111/2952), do you know what part that should be specified in? I just tried a few things, but got errors each time - I think because the code presently isn't aware of endpoints (first and last indices). Also, you mentioned "and v" - what's the difference? I suppose with NURBS we're dealing with the same U & V as "UV mapping". Beyond that, unsure.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Spline.html#bpy.types.Spline.use_endpoint_u  Use same as here, it's a property of the spline.  u is the curve resolution  v the surface.