How to make a dynamic arrow from a vertex to another face center
I would like to make some arrows, each of whose shaft is a cubic bezier curve, beginning (tail) at a mesh vertex, and ending (head) at the center of a mesh face.
(The "center" of a face can be defined in any of several ways; e.g. centroid of vertices, or centroid of area; either of these is fine.)
The following picture shows three such arrows (tediously created by hand, not dynamic):

The arrow heads and tails should stay attached to the respective mesh features, as the meshes are translated/rotated/scaled and deformed (without structural changes).  The directions at the arrow heads and tails should always stay pointed in the directions of the respective mesh surface normals.
How can I create such arrows?

This reads like a job offer.

These other questions seem related to this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13452/attaching-a-curve-by-its-endpoints-to-two-spheres https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/dynamic-way-to-connect-the-balls-with-rods  Specifically, it looks like the answer to those questions ("use a hook modifier") will address the subproblem of attaching the bezier curve's endpoints to two other movable objects.

Geometry Nodes should work, too. How do you define the face where the arrows should point to? The starting vertex could be defined by a vertex group.

You can do it with geometry nodes.
The nodes belong to the source object (from which the arrow originates).
Then it takes a target object (which the arrow points to)
The nodes take 4 user inputs:

Target object (the object which contains the target face)
Point index (the index of the point from which the arrow originates)
Face index (the index of the face the arrow points to)
Handle length (controls how early the arrow starts curving and also controls the diameter and size of the cone)

This is the main geometry node setup:

This is the Get_Directions node group:

This is the Create_Cone group:

I made the size of the cone and the diameter of the arrow dependent on Handle_Length.
File:


Alternative for versions that don't have "Align rotation to vector" node:
The Create_Cone group will be like this, where the change is only the part that connects to the rotation:

Alternative file:


Beautiful!  And full of great educational material for me to study.

One problem I notice: when I bring it up in blender 4.0.2 (which is the latest blender version available on my ubuntu linux distribution, at the moment), the cone is pointed in the direct opposite of the correct direction.  But it's correct in the 4.3.alpha which I built from source code.

@DonHatch, to solve the cone issue, just remove the multiplication by -1 that is connected to the Arrow_Direction output of the Get_Directions group. I'll leave the answer as is because it's tested and working for Blender 4.2.2 on Windows. If you consider the answer solves you question, please mark it as answered

@DonHatch, another thing to pay attention to: the face orientation of your objects. Since it's using the normal vector, if faces are inverted, the normals are also inverted. Also, the scales (scales must probably be applied to avoid distortions). And if you have a negative scale, that might cause the same problem.

I'd like to get something that works with 4.0 as well (and farther back, if feasible), so that I, and anyone I share blend files with, aren't forced to upgrade to a blender version that isn't universally available yet in order to view and work with my blend-files.  I'll try to see if I can figure out why it's not working on 4.0- that'll be a good way for me to get familiar with what you've done here.

@DonHatch, I told you above and updated the answer too. The solution is very simple.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Summary of chat: the solution didn't work in blender 4.0 because it uses a "Align rotation to vector" node which didn't exist yet.  The alternative solution works.

There's a problem: I need arrows to go from mesh object A to B to C and then back to A (as shown in my original mockup image). But when I try to hook that up using the solution given here, it fails with an error message to the terminal window, saying "Dependency cycle detected", and listing the names of the objects participating in the cycle.  Can this be avoided?  (I see one way to do it: make each arrow be an additional object, with geometry node group inputs referring to its "from" and "to" object; then there will be no cycles.)

Yeah... I think your solution would be the best in this case. Empty meshes being the arrows.

I added an answer showing a solution that supports cycles, based on your solution.

This is based on Daniel Möller's solution, improved so that cycles are supported.
E.g. you can have a cycle of arrows among objects A->B->C->A as shown in the original mockup picture, or an arrow from an object to itself.
The arrow is a separate object, so you can even have arrows between arrows, as shown here.

I constructed the graph in blender 4.3.alpha (built from source code from github).

Note that it contains both an Align Rotation to Vector node (the simplest way to do it in blender 4.2 and higher, but doesn't exist pre-4.2) and Daniel Möller's alternative implementation of that node, which I made into a node group Rotation to Vector: Z Axis (shim for pre 4.2).
Either one should work in 4.2+ (just switch the Transform's Rotation input from one to the other); I hooked it up to the latter, so that the solution will work in pre-4.2 as well (tested on 4.0).
Here is the shim node group, expanded (using Tab):

One non-obvious thing I noticed, in the shim node group: there is an Equal node, whose tolerance epsilon is displayed as 0.0000, which seems like it wouldn't work well.
But if you hover over the value or edit it, it becomes clear that it's actually 1e-5, which is a sensible value.
I don't know whether there's a way to make it display this important value better, but I changed the title of this node from Equal to Equals zero (within 1e-5) to try to call this out.

